# Pod does not see secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

The pod that created in the same `default` namespace as it's secret does not see values from it.

Secret's file contains following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: backend-secret
data:
  SECRET_KEY: <base64 of value>
  DEBUG: <base64 of value>
```

After creating this secret via `kubectl create -f backend-secret.yaml` I'm launching pod with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  containers:
    - image: backend
      name: backend
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: dockerhub-credentials
  volumes:
  - name: secret
    secret:
      secretName: backend-secret
```

But pod crashes after trying to extract this environment variable via python's `os.environ['DEBUG']` line.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mount secret as volume, it will be mounted in a defined directory where key name will be the file name. For example click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-files-permissions)

If you want to access secrets from the environment into your pod then you need to use secret in an environment variable like following.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  containers:
    - image: backend
      name: backend
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
      env:
      - name: DEBUG
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: backend-secret
            key: DEBUG
      - name: SECRET_KEY
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: backend-secret
            key: SECRET_KEY
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: dockerhub-credentials
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: Could you share the code that I should modify in my file?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've used these lines at `Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers`:

```
  containers:
  - name: backend
    image: zuber93/wts_backend
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    envFrom:
    - secretRef:
        name: backend-secret
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8000
```